# Latitude 7390: No intel_backlight directory, can't adjust backlight

Tags: fedora, xorg, dell-latitude, backlight

I've been searching the 'net for an hour or two now about this problem, but the 9370 apparently uses some weird implementation of i915.

I'm running Fedora 32 and i3, so I'm using Xorg.

Here's what I've done so far:

Set `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor i915.enable_dpcd_backlight=1` in kernel params

Installed `xbacklight`, which gives `no outputs have backlight property`

Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder)

Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363087/13-10-cant-adjust-dell-laptop-backlight)

I don't think the above two solutions would work, because, well,

```
[root@localhost /sys/class/backlight]# ls
dell_backlight
```

I can only echo things into `brightness` as root, and when I do so, it has no effect.

Am I missing a kernel param or something? Do I have to install something else?

EDIT: The backlight works out of the box on Ubuntu. Why? What does Ubuntu do differently?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what happens if you try different values for the acpi_backlight kernel parameter.  Please pick one of [the following,](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#Hardware%20interfaces) try it, see what happens:

```
acpi_backlight=video
acpi_backlight=vendor
acpi_backlight=native
acpi_backlight=none
```

If none of them work, then I would suggest removing it from the kernel parameters altogether.

Comment: `acpi_backlight=vendor` gives me `dell_backlight`. Everything else gives me nothing.